# Attribute directive cannot bind to a host component property

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have this:

```
<my-cmp input>
  hello
</my-cmp>
```

my-cmp has `@Input() disabled`, and `input` is another directive like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[input]',
  host:{
    '[disabled]': 'true'
  }
})
```

Why is it complaining that `disabled` is not declared as an Input in my-cmp?

Basically, I want a directive that applies some bindings on the host element.

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ocvWr54phFXKXIiZiLFN?p=preview) is the plunkr

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your directive is only working for one type of component, and it's not how directives should be used.

if you add `input` directive to a div, it'll not work since `disabled` is not a known native property. Same goes for your component. I guess it's because directives are loaded before components.

To fix this, you should properly use your disabled attribute:

```
<my-cmp [disabled]="true">
  hello
</my-cmp>
```

*N.B*: You also made a typo on `MyComponent`, `@Directive` should be `@Component` and should have a `template` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove square brackets from the host:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[input]',
    host:{
       'disabled': 'true'
    }
})
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tWcj7WSnJGvazEi8tfIM?p=preview)

Comment: Up, sorry, you need to remove square brackets from host instead of selector, i modified my answer. Now you have selected="true" as attribute.

Comment: even if it is happy, it is still not bound I think:

https://plnkr.co/edit/8AbfBIlSGv3Bkz9bIg0w?p=preview

it prints, undefined.